# Django: authenticate & login function works but user isn't actually logged in

Tags: python, django

i have a problem related to logging a user in in Django.

in the lines of code below, i have tried to use the login function to log the user in, but when the user gets to the main page the page tells them to log in (meaning that django told me that they're not authenticated); the login function doesn't raise any errors at all.

login/login.py

```py
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.Login(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            db_user = AuthBackend().authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if db_user is not None:
                login(request, db_user, backend="django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main:index"))
            else:
                return render(request, "login/login.html", {"form": form, "error": "Incorrect"})

        else:
            return render(request, "login/login.html", {"form": form})

    return render(request, "login/login.html", {"form": forms.Login()})
```

main/templates/main/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timeline</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'account' %}">Account</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login:login' %}">Log In</a>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

also, im very new to stack and making questions, so if i have to provide other info i would appreciate the reminder and ill try to be helpful as possible. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `login.py`:

```
...
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.Login(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            db_user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if db_user is not None:
                login(request, db_user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main:index"))
            else:
                return render(request, "login/login.html", {"form": form, "error": "Incorrect"})

        else:
            return render(request, "login/login.html", {"form": form})

    return render(request, "login/login.html", {"form": forms.Login()})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).